# Execute multiple RegExp patterns in "one shot" using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am in the process of slowly rewriting my blog and part of it is adding support for comments. In my mind I want to take the commenting a step further and allow people to use [BBcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode) shortcodes.

Searching around for ready to use libraries was not a success, as most of these are either abandoned, bugged and so on. With that in mind I decided to spend some time and create the necessary regex patterns to replace the BB codes I want to allow in comments with their relevant substitutes.

My problem is that I need to execute all these in "one go" on the comment content if take makes sense, perhaps using some sort of array/map. The API is written using TypeScript and execution speed/CPU usage is vital as the API sits on serverless computing.

Please see what I have created below (special thanks to [urlregex.com](https://urlregex.com/) and [devdreamz.com](https://devdreamz.com/question/756745-replace-multiple-characters-thats-inside-of-a-bbcode-tag-only-and-not-effect-a)):

```js
const STRONG = '(?:\\[b\\]([a-zA-Z\\s\\d]+)\\[\\/b\\])+';
const regexSTRONG = new RegExp(`${STRONG}`, 'gi');
const substSTRONG = '<strong>$1</strong>';

let str = `[b]bolded text[/b]`;
let result = str.replace(regexSTRONG, substSTRONG);
console.log('Substitution result: ', result);

const ITALIC = '(?:\\[i\\]([a-zA-Z\\s\\d]+)\\[\\/i\\])+';
const regexITALIC = new RegExp(`${ITALIC}`, 'gi');
const substITALIC = '<em>$1</em>';

str = `[i]italicized text[/i]`;
result = str.replace(regexITALIC, substITALIC);
console.log('Substitution result: ', result);

const UNDERLINED = '(?:\\[u\\]([a-zA-Z\\s\\d]+)\\[\\/u\\])+';
const regexUNDERLINED = new RegExp(`${UNDERLINED}`, 'gi');
const substUNDERLINED = '<ins>$1</ins>';

str = `[u]underlined text[/u]`;
result = str.replace(regexUNDERLINED, substUNDERLINED);
console.log('Substitution result: ', result);

const STRIKETHROUGH = '(?:\\[s\\]([a-zA-Z\\s\\d]+)\\[\\/s\\])+';
const regexSTRIKETHROUGH = new RegExp(`${STRIKETHROUGH}`, 'gi');
const substSTRIKETHROUGH = '<del>$1</del>';

str = `[s]strikethrough text[/s]`;
result = str.replace(regexSTRIKETHROUGH, substSTRIKETHROUGH);
console.log('Substitution result: ', result);

const uURL = '(?:\\[url\\]((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\\/\\/)?)(?:[\\-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\\.\\-]+|(?:www\\.|[\\-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\\.\\-]+)((?:\\/[\\+~%\\/\\.\\w\\-_]*)?\\??(?:[\\-\\+=&;%@\\.\\w_]*)#?(?:[\\.\\!\\/\\\\\\w]*))?)\\[\\/url\\])+';
const regexURL = new RegExp(`${uURL}`, 'gi');
const substURL = '<a href="$1">$1</a>';

str = `[url]https://en.wikipedia.org[/url]`;
result = str.replace(regexURL, substURL);
console.log('Substitution result: ', result);

const uURLALT = '(?:\\[url=((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\\/\\/)?)(?:[\\-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\\.\\-]+|(?:www\\.|[\\-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\\.\\-]+)((?:\\/[\\+~%\\/\\.\\w\\-_]*)?\\??(?:[\\-\\+=&;%@\\.\\w_]*)#?(?:[\\.\\!\\/\\\\\\w]*))?)\\]([a-zA-Z\\s\\d]+)\\[\\/url\\])+';
const regexURLALT = new RegExp(`${uURLALT}`, 'gi');
const substURLALT = '<a href="$1">$5</a>';

str = `[url=https://en.wikipedia.org]English Wikipedia[/url]`;
result = str.replace(regexURLALT, substURLALT);
console.log('Substitution result: ', result);

const IMG = '(?:\\[img=((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\\/\\/)?)(?:[\\-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\\.\\-]+|(?:www\\.|[\\-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\\.\\-]+)((?:\\/[\\+~%\\/\\.\\w\\-_]*)?\\??(?:[\\-\\+=&;%@\\.\\w_]*\\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png))#?(?:[\\.\\!\\/\\\\\\w]*))?)\\]([a-zA-Z\\s\\d]+)\\[\\/img\\])+';
const regexIMG = new RegExp(`${IMG}`, 'gi');
const substIMG = '<img src="$1" alt="$5" />';

str = `[img=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png]Example Image[/img]`;
result = str.replace(regexIMG, substIMG);
console.log('Substitution result: ', result);

const QUOTE = '(?:\\[quote\\]([a-zA-Z\\s\\d]+)\\[\\/quote\\])+';
const regexQUOTE = new RegExp(`${QUOTE}`, 'gi');
const substQUOTE = '<blockquote><p>$1</p></blockquote>';

str = `[quote]quoted text[/quote]`;
result = str.replace(regexQUOTE, substQUOTE);
console.log('Substitution result: ', result);

const QUOTEALT = '(?:\\[quote=\\"([a-zA-Z\\s\\d]+)\\"\\]([a-zA-Z\\s\\d]+)\\[\\/quote\\])+';
const regexQUOTEALT = new RegExp(`${QUOTEALT}`, 'gi');
const substQUOTEALT = '<blockquote><p>$2</p><cite>$1</cite></blockquote>';

str = `[quote="author"]quoted text[/quote]`;
result = str.replace(regexQUOTEALT, substQUOTEALT);
console.log('Substitution result: ', result);

const CODE = '(?:\\[code])([^[]*(?:\\[(?!\\/?code[\\]=])[^[]*)*)(?:\\[\\/code])+';
const regexCODE = new RegExp(`${CODE}`, 'gi');
const substCODE = '<code><pre>$1</pre></code>';

str = `[code]monospaced text[/code]`;
result = str.replace(regexCODE, substCODE);
console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Unfortunately my JavaScript/TypeScript knowledge is quite limited and I am still in the process of getting used to them whilst I develop my blog.

Please let me know how I can achieve my goal.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you use a loop and check everything manually . This will increase performance a lot but will decrease readability .

Comment: I did something similar in PHP some years ago, and I found that it was necessary to do multiple passes, first pass to replace the string with a reference, then another tor replace the reference with the content.  This allowed scope to deal with sub-patterns and avoid problems with overlapping patterns.  Trying to build a regex that coped with multiple patterns just got way too unwieldy.  It's also worth considering whether to cache the result when the content is saved, versus every time its served.

Comment: @YasserCHENIK Thanks, I don't care about readability - I want performance and less CPU as possible.

Comment: @DaveMeehan Thanks, trying to understand what you mean. Also, this will be done once before saving the content, not when serving the content.

Comment: sub-patterns e.g `[b][i]xxx[/i][/b]`.  Whilst `[b][i]xxx[/b][/i]` might not be valid, it usually needs some sort of handling, even if only to reject the save.  My implementation was more like markdown, sometimes spanning multiple lines, which made things trickier.  If you are only doing on save, then is performance really an issue, or just a concern?  I suspect that compound regex for the sake of avoiding multiple passes might not actually help (internally its potentially doing some form of multiple comparison for each sequence).

Comment: Rather than regexp, you might want to look at some form of Abstract Syntax Tree parser, some are code generators which specifically parse and validate your specific syntax.

Comment: @DaveMeehan Thanks for your input, indeed I never planned to account for sub-patterns (don't think I will just for the sake of post comments). I would like to keep things simple for this purpose just using Regex. Performance is not really an issue per say, but CPU usage/time is. The longer it takes, the more you get charged on serverless computing pricing models, so I would like to be as "short" as possible on usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following solution:

```
const STRONG = '(?:\\[b\\]([a-zA-Z\\s\\d,.\\\'";:\\-_=+*?!\\(\\)\\{\\}\\\\\\/|@]+)\\[\\/b\\])+';
const regexSTRONG = new RegExp(`${STRONG}`, 'gi');
const substSTRONG = '<strong>$1</strong>';

const ITALIC = '(?:\\[i\\]([a-zA-Z\\s\\d,.\\\'";:\\-_=+*?!\\(\\)\\{\\}\\\\\\/|@]+)\\[\\/i\\])+';
const regexITALIC = new RegExp(`${ITALIC}`, 'gi');
const substITALIC = '<em>$1</em>';

const UNDERLINED = '(?:\\[u\\]([a-zA-Z\\s\\d,.\\\'";:\\-_=+*?!\\(\\)\\{\\}\\\\\\/|@]+)\\[\\/u\\])+';
const regexUNDERLINED = new RegExp(`${UNDERLINED}`, 'gi');
const substUNDERLINED = '<ins>$1</ins>';

const STRIKETHROUGH = '(?:\\[s\\]([a-zA-Z\\s\\d,.\\\'";:\\-_=+*?!\\(\\)\\{\\}\\\\\\/|@]+)\\[\\/s\\])+';
const regexSTRIKETHROUGH = new RegExp(`${STRIKETHROUGH}`, 'gi');
const substSTRIKETHROUGH = '<del>$1</del>';

const uURL = '(?:\\[url\\]((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\\/\\/)?)(?:[\\-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\\.\\-]+|(?:www\\.|[\\-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\\.\\-]+)((?:\\/[\\+~%\\/\\.\\w\\-_]*)?\\??(?:[\\-\\+=&;%@\\.\\w_]*)#?(?:[\\.\\!\\/\\\\\\w]*))?)\\[\\/url\\])+';
const regexURL = new RegExp(`${uURL}`, 'gi');
const substURL = '<a href="$1">$1</a>';

const uURLALT = '(?:\\[url=((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\\/\\/)?)(?:[\\-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\\.\\-]+|(?:www\\.|[\\-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\\.\\-]+)((?:\\/[\\+~%\\/\\.\\w\\-_]*)?\\??(?:[\\-\\+=&;%@\\.\\w_]*)#?(?:[\\.\\!\\/\\\\\\w]*))?)\\]([a-zA-Z\\s\\d]+)\\[\\/url\\])+';
const regexURLALT = new RegExp(`${uURLALT}`, 'gi');
const substURLALT = '<a href="$1">$5</a>';

const IMG = '(?:\\[img=((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\\/\\/)?)(?:[\\-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\\.\\-]+|(?:www\\.|[\\-;:&=\\+\\$,\\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\\.\\-]+)((?:\\/[\\+~%\\/\\.\\w\\-_]*)?\\??(?:[\\-\\+=&;%@\\.\\w_]*\\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png))#?(?:[\\.\\!\\/\\\\\\w]*))?)\\]([a-zA-Z\\s\\d]+)\\[\\/img\\])+';
const regexIMG = new RegExp(`${IMG}`, 'gi');
const substIMG = '<img src="$1" alt="$5" />';

const QUOTE = '(?:\\[quote\\]([a-zA-Z\\s\\d,.\\\'";:\\-_=+*?!\\(\\)\\{\\}\\\\\\/|@]+)\\[\\/quote\\])+';
const regexQUOTE = new RegExp(`${QUOTE}`, 'gi');
const substQUOTE = '<blockquote><p>$1</p></blockquote>';

const QUOTEALT = '(?:\\[quote=\\"([a-zA-Z\\s\\d]+)\\"\\]([a-zA-Z\\s\\d,.\\\'";:\\-_=+*?!\\(\\)\\{\\}\\\\\\/|@]+)\\[\\/quote\\])+';
const regexQUOTEALT = new RegExp(`${QUOTEALT}`, 'gi');
const substQUOTEALT = '<blockquote><p>$2</p><cite>$1</cite></blockquote>';

const CODE = '(?:\\[code])([^[]*(?:\\[(?!\\/?code[\\]=])[^[]*)*)(?:\\[\\/code])+';
const regexCODE = new RegExp(`${CODE}`, 'gi');
const substCODE = '<code><pre>$1</pre></code>';

const NEWLINE = '(.+?)(\\n|$)+';
const regexNEWLINE = new RegExp(`${NEWLINE}`, 'gi');
const substNEWLINE = '<p>$1</p>';

const RegexArray: readonly RegExp[] = [regexSTRONG, 
regexITALIC, regexUNDERLINED, regexSTRIKETHROUGH, regexURL, regexURLALT, regexIMG, regexQUOTE, regexQUOTEALT, regexCODE];

const SubstArray: readonly string[] = [substSTRONG, 
substITALIC, substUNDERLINED, substSTRIKETHROUGH, substURL, substURLALT, substIMG, substQUOTE, substQUOTEALT, substCODE];

// https://github.com/dsblv/string-replace-async
// Fixed up a bit.
const replaceAsync = async (text: string, searchValue: RegExp, replacer: any): Promise<string> => {
  try {
    if (typeof replacer === "function") {
      // 1. Run fake pass of `replace`, collect values from `replacer` calls
      // 2. Resolve them with `Promise.all`
      // 3. Run `replace` with resolved values
      var values:any = [];
      String.prototype.replace.call(text, searchValue, function () {
        values.push(replacer.apply(undefined, arguments));
        return "";
      });
      return Promise.all(values).then(function (resolvedValues) {
        return String.prototype.replace.call(text, searchValue, function () {
          return resolvedValues.shift();
        });
      });
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve(
        String.prototype.replace.call(text, searchValue, replacer)
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
}

const parseBBCode = async (text: string): Promise<string> => {
  try{
    for (var i = 0; i < RegexArray.length; i++) {
      text = await replaceAsync(text, RegexArray[i], SubstArray[i]);
    }
    return text;
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
};

async function test()
{
  let text = `Hello World! This is just a [b]test[/b] to see how this idea [i]works[/i]. Maybe it [s]doesn't work at all[/s].
  We all like to code: [code]var Banana = 0;[/code]. 
  How are [url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72170180/execute-multiple-regexp-patterns-in-one-shot-using-typescript]links[/url] working?
  How about images? [img=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png]Example Image[/img]`;

  text = await parseBBCode(text);

  const result = text.replace(regexNEWLINE, substNEWLINE);

  console.log(result)
};

test();
```

It's `async`/`await`-able and works on replacements concurrently, overall pretty fast.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to improve this feel free to comment and I will update my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was the one who downvoted (I'm happy to retract it if you improve the answer). I typed in my reason last night and forgot to hit Enter. So: Using `async`/`await` or Promises on normally synchronous code is completely unnecessary. It won't help you in any way (it'll still block the event loop), and will force you to make all of your code async. It'll probably also cause some performace overhead. If you're concerned about a potentially long-running code blocking the event loop, you could use zero-delay `setTimeout`s, but you'd be better off with a `WebWorker` in that case.

Comment: @FZs  Read my post..  it's serverless computing, it's all async. Rarely see synchronous code. Checkout cloudflare workers.... I won't improve my answer because it's not needed, if someone is unhappy with async it's only a matter of removing async.

Comment: **It's my fault.** I was typing up a long explanation of why `async` is unnecessary here, when I noticed that `replacer` is a function that is passed in from the outside, and so it could be async. I must've been really tired last night. Now my vote is locked by the system and I can't undo my vote unless the answer is edited. I'll make a minor edit if you don't mind... you can even roll it back. And I'm sorry again.